# How to change position of SVG path (elliptical arc) with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, syntax

I'm looking to change position of a few created SVG shapes with CSS. I've had no trouble positioning them from the beginning, and I've been able to re-position other objects like rectangles and circles with CSS. But I can't figure out how to do it with a path. I've done searches both here and through Google search for several hours, but haven't found any usable clues. I'm beginning to suspect that there is something about SVG paths I haven't understood fully yet, but at the same time I can't help but think that it might just be down to me not understanding the correct syntax in CSS.

Below is an SVG elliptical arc path I've created. I'd like to move it anywhere within view (so I can spot the difference and work from there). Can someone tell me if I'm lacking some knowledge about how paths work (contrary to how rectangles work in this regard), or if I just need the proper syntax in CSS?

Please note: I do NOT want to animate it in any way, just move it to a new position if possible.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="cockpit" d="M 0 0 A 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" fill="lightblue" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You could use `transform`  properties like `translate()` to shift an element position. Otherwise you can convert your path to **relative command** and change the starting `M` command values as described by [Lea Verou: "Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute commands"](https://lea.verou.me/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital A in your path `M 0 0 A 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0` makes it *Arc* at an ***absolute*** position

If you convert that whole path to use a ***relative*** `a` position: `M0 0 a 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0`
(use https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/# for more complex paths)

You can use the first `M x y` notation to position the path anywhere *in the viewBox*

```html
<style>
 svg  { background:hotpink; height:50px }
 path { fill:lightblue; stroke:blue  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 55 10">
  <path d="M 0 7 a 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 55 10">
  <path d="M 14 7 a 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 55 10">
  <path d="M 4 9 a 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 55 10">
  <path d="M 4 12 a 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, this made me realize that I was indeed right, in that I *was* missing some knowledge about how paths work. This is the most useful answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the path using transform/translate either as a CSS property (first example) or as an attribute (second example).

I also added the viewBox attribute to the SVG element -- then it's easier to see where you place the path in the SVG.

```css
svg {
  background: orange;
}

path {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 20">
  <path id="cockpit" d="M 0 0 A 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" fill="lightblue"
    stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="5"/>
</svg>
```

```css
svg {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 20">
  <path id="cockpit" d="M 0 0 A 50 37.5 0 0 1 50 0" fill="lightblue"
    stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="5" transform="translate(10 10)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, eventually I was able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got on track with 'offset-path', and with some tinkering I managed to understand enough about how it works to move the path to a new position:

```
offset-path: path("M237.5 50");
```